# What is an example of a cyclic group with exactly 6 generators?

Tags: cyclic-groups

Hi I need an example of a cyclic group with exactly 6 generators, thank you.

Comment: What do you know about the number of generators? I have an answer (well, more than one), but am concerned about what facts to use. And it is always good to know what you have tried.

Comment: See related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130871/give-an-example-of-a-cyclic-group-with-6-generators?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

If it has $6$ generators, and since $e$ is never a generator (unless it's the trivial group, which it's not), then the group you are looking for must have at least $7$ elements. How many cyclic groups with $7$ elements do you know? (hint: essentially just one.) For that single most immediate candidate as an answer, is it true that each of its elements other than $e$ is a generator? (Hint: the order of an element in a cyclic group is easy to compute. What do you know about it?)

Comment: Must it have precisely 7 elements though? That seems to be false.  Certainly the group with 7 elements works, but what of a group with 14 elements? What of others?

Comment: A4 (alternating subgroup of S4) is what Ittay is talking about.

Comment: thanks @JMoravitz I meant to write "at least 7 elements" (corrected now). My point was that a very minimalistic approach leads to a candidate which actually solves the question.

Comment: @JMoravitz 7, 9, 14, 18.

Comment: @YunusSyed I don't see anything about A4 in what Ittay wrote.  His answer was entirely about cyclic groups, and A4 isn't cyclic.